# Spacy - python - for loop to process several sentences

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, spacy

Python / spacy question

I am trying to figure out how to allow to use a for loop to get spacy to:

- Go through a data frame of sentences (called "sentences"),row by row. (Each row contains a sentence as a string)
- For each sentence, analyze what the part of speech is of each token in the sentence
- Store each part of speech in a column in a data frame (i.e text1 is the part of speech of the first token, text2 is the second one, etc)

Is there an easier way to get everything into a data frame (or straight to an excel file)?

I need to analyze 100 sentences, so I don't want to analyze each sentence with a new line of code. I thought a for loop could make this automate this.

This is my code:

```py
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["text1", "text2", "text3", "text4", "text5", "text6", "text7", "text8", "text9",
                            "text10", "text11", "text12", "text13", "text14", "text15", "text16",
                            "text17", "text18", "text19", "text20"])

max = len(sentences)
j = 0     
for i in range(1, max):
    doc = nlp(sentence_list[i])
    for token in doc: 
        pos = token.pos_
        df[i,j]= pos 
        j = j + 1
```

I get this error message:

```
PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance.  Consider joining all columns at once using pd.concat(axis=1) instead. To get a de-fragmented frame, use `newframe = frame.copy()`
```

Comment: That's not an error. It's a warning telling you that you might get low performances. If your code doesn't work, then you should post the error you're getting (if any) or the wrong results you get

Comment: where are the imports ?  users need sufficient code to replicate the problem:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that each text will vary in word count, and so the number of "sub-columns" will be dynamic. I suggest using the following code as **starting point**, and then improve column `POS_Analysis` appearance, via Pandas opperations.

```py
import spacy
import pandas as pd

# Building my own `df1`, it should look similar to yours
texts = ["text1", "text2", "more texts", "text 100"]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(texts, columns =['texts'])

# Loading spaCy model
model_to_use = "en_core_web_lg"  # Or use the path to your own model
nlp = spacy.load(model_to_use)

# 'STARTING POINT' CODE
pos_list = []
for doc in nlp.pipe(df1['texts']):
    token_pos = []
    for token in doc:
        token_pos.append(
            {
                "Token text": token.text,
                "Universal POS tag set": token.pos_,
                "Fine-grained POS": token.tag_,
                # # Include the rest if you want them...
                # "Lemma": token.lemma_,
                # "Syntactic dependency relation": token.dep_,
                # "Orthographic features": token.shape_,
                # "consist of alphabetic characters": token.is_alpha,
                # "belongs to stop list": token.is_stop
            }
        )
    pos_list.append(token_pos)

df1['POS_Analysis'] = pos_list

print(df1.head())
```

An **example output** looks like:

```
text                                       POS_Analysis
0  Net income was $9.4 million compared to the pr...  [{'Token text': 'Net', 'Universal POS tag set'...
1  Revenue exceeded twelve billion dollars, with ...  [{'Token text': 'Revenue', 'Universal POS tag ...
2                      I don't have any entity in me  [{'Token text': 'I', 'Universal POS tag set': ...
```

I think I can update this answer, but as requested on the comments to your original post, you will need to clarify your request a bit more.